# Spring JPA Child entity id is null after Parent is saved

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is the first project in my entire carrier where DB side id generation is used and I really don't understand how to have both: this id generation strategy and clear code base.

Classic case. I have the Parent Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "parent")
@Table(name = "parent", schema = "schema")
class ParentEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "parent",
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private val _children: MutableSet<ChildEntity> = mutableSetOf()

    val children
        get() = _children.toList()

    fun addChild(child: ChildEntity): ChildEntity {
        _children.add(child)
        child.parent = this
        return child
    }

    fun removeChild(child: ChildEntity): Boolean {
        return _children.remove(child)
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || other !is ParentEntity) return false

        return id != null && id == other.id
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return javaClass.hashCode()
    }
}
```

And the Child Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "child")
@Table(name = "child", schema = "schema")
class ChildEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    var title: String? = null,

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    var parent: AgileTeamEntity
) {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || other !is ChildEntity) return false

        return id != null && id == other.id
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return javaClass.hashCode()
    }
}
```

In my service I save child by adding it to parent and calling `save` method like this:

```
@Transactional
override fun addChildToParent(parentId: Long, input: ChildInputDto): ChildDto {
    val currentParent = parentService.findParentById(parentId) ?: throw NotFoundException("Parent not found")
            
    val newChild = childMapper.dtoToEntity(input)

    val addedChild = currentParent.addChild(newChild)

    val savedParent = parentService.update(currentParent) // Here I call `parentRepository.save(currentParent)`

    return childMapper.entityToDto(addedChild) // here added child has id == null
}
```

I know that children in `savedParent` object has new ids but what am I supposed to do if `id` is the only property of `child` that is unique thus this is the only property that I can use to filter the `child` I need from `savedParent`?

Side notes:

- I went through [this great article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) and followed the guidelines Vlad dropped but this seems to be not working in case of child entities, since children entities does not behave consistently across entity state transitions. ...Or am I missing something?
- Of course there is no such an issue if I use application side generated UUID identifiers but there is no option to do such reworks for now.

Answer (score 1):

Spring's Save method is confusing and are a cause of inconsistent behavior, as it does different things depending on what is passed in. Save will look at the entity passed in. If it figures the entity exists, it will call JPA's merge on it, but it if doesn't, it'll use JPA's persist. They have very different behavior.

In this case though, your entity exists and Spring is using merge on it. What you are hitting is because of section 3.2.7.1 "Merging Detached Entity State" of the JPA specification. The merge api will detect it is managed as this is the same instance you read in the same transaction, so nothing needs to be done on the parent itself. The issue is with the child references - merge will cascade over it, but unlike persist, it will make a copy of what is passed in to manage. This managed child instance is what gets its ID set when the transaction commits or is flushed. Merge will set the parent's child reference to point at this managed child instance so that everything in the parent graph is managed going forward.

Your code just needs to use the child from the savedParent's _children set. Good luck knowing which that was though, as it is likely they have different hashcode values now.

Instead of the `parentService.update(currentParent)` call, you might use:

```
@Transactional
override fun addChildToParent(parentId: Long, input: ChildInputDto): ChildDto {
    val currentParent = parentService.findParentById(parentId) ?: throw NotFoundException("Parent not found")
            
    val newChild = childMapper.dtoToEntity(input)
    val addedChild = currentParent.addChild(newChild)
    //using flush to force the statement now, 
    // ensuring the ID is assigned before the transaction commits
    addedChild  = childRepository.saveAndFlush(addedChild ) 

    return childMapper.entityToDto(addedChild) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Chris! Yeah, this approach works but the thing is that `parentService.update()` method is more than just save: it spawn app event, save some metadata and do this for every direct (parent property) or indirect (parent children) change of parent entity. I think I need to redesign somehow then...

Comment: You can still call update after the saveAndFlush call - JPA will consider it a no-op as the entity is already managed and nothing will have changed on it. I don't know your lifecycle methods or what might be being done to comment more on how best to manage that though.